# How to input wordpress tags for a post via url

Tags: javascript, wordpress-theming, taxonomy

I am trying to add tags via a URL to front end *via* a URL query string and I am using the following JavaScript function to achieve this:

```js
<script>
   var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&'); // substr(1) to remove the `#`
   for(var i = 0; i < hashParams.length; i++){
      var p = hashParams[i].split('=');
      document.getElementById(p[0]).value = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);;
   }
</script>
```

It works for most fields for example https://quotemetoets.co.za/add-listing/#name=stack

But it won't enter the tag for the tags field via a URL. What should I do to get it to add tags *via* URL query?